# how to return to the previous View after submit using HTML

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2017

I have a View/form named `ApplicationperPerson`, in that view I have a button that redirects the user to a `CreatePerson` View/Form when a name of a person is not on the list.  After entering all the persons basic info the button submit does not take me back to previous View/form `ApplicationperPerson` to continue filling the required info that is needed.
I wish to use `returnurl` to go back from `CreatePerson` to `ApplicationperPerson`.
May I have an example on how to use returnurl in html and c# or an example to make this --

> href="@Url.Action("Create","CreatePerson")" class="btn btn-info
>   btn-group-xs">Create Person if is not on the select list --return
>   to ApplicationperPerson

Comment: What is your current submit code? If you post that, we can help you modify it to do a redirect after it does the work.

Comment: Something's wrong with the code you have there. You'll need to the do the redirect _server-side_, so we need your `CreatePerson` method.